# How to solve float lost problem in this template

Tags: floats, templates

I am using [this](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/structured-general-purpose-assignment) template, but when I add `\begin{figure}` in the '\problemAnswer{}' there always has a error **"Float(s) lost. \end{document}"**. Is anyway to fix this bug?

Comment: Welcome, you cannot use float with this template.

Comment: Simply use `\problemAnswer{\includegraphics{duck}}`.

Comment: Off topic: I cannot advice to use this template at all.

Comment: It's not at all mandatory that `\includegraphics` is in a `figure` environment: think to it as creating a big letter in a fancy alphabet.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks, it's working! but how can I add caption to the graph?

Comment: You can use captionof from package caption. But, do you need a caption? Think about why we have captions.

Answer (score 2):

The way the template is set up, you cannot use `figure`  environments within `\problemAnswer`s. Why would you in the first place?  Just include the picture as is, if you want you can add a `center` environment.

```
\problemAnswer{ % Answer
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.75\columnwidth]{example_figure} % Example image
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]
}
```

---

I cannot recommend the template, see also [Why should I avoid templates?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390683/why-should-you-avoid-to-use-complex-templates)